# success message displaying before submit

Tags: php

I have a contact form which requires validation. The problem is that the success message is displaying before I even hit submit. Obviously it should only display the success message once the form has actually passed validation and submitted.

```
<?php
$error = ""; $successMessage = "";
$fname = $email = $message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $error .= "First name is required.<br>";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $error .= "Only letters and white space allowed.<br>"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $error .= "Email is required.<br>";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $error .= "Invalid email format.<br>"; 
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["content"])) {
      $error .= "Message is required.<br>";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["content"]);
  }

}

 if ($error != "") {

            $error = '<div class="formerror" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong><br></p>' . $error . '</div>';
 } else {

     $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent, we\'ll get back to you ASAP!</div>';


            }

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


?>
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="cform">
    <input type="text" class="contactfield cformbottom" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" name="name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">

    <input type="email" class="contactfield cformbottom" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">


    <textarea class="contactfield" id="content" name="content" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message" value="<?php echo $message;?>"></textarea>
          </div>
  <input type="submit" class="newsbut" value="Submit">
</form><br>
         <div id="error"><? echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>
```

Comment: use a ternary operator or `isset()` on the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the conditional where you're creating the success message. You already set the $error variable to "". Now, you're saying that if it is "" then create the success message. So, no matter whether the request is a POST or not, the success message will be created. Move that conditional inside the block that checks whether it's a POST request.

Comment: Silly me, I moved it inside the code block and it now works as it should :) I haven't asked that many questions on here before and just realised there is something else I want to ask about this. Can I ask here or do I need to create a new question?

Answer (score 0):

All of your validation should be within this condition:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

Then, in the HTML, you would check if the variable(s) exist. For example,

```
<?php echo isset($successMessage) ? $error . $successMessage : "" ?>
```